# Is the Uncertainty Principle valid for a macroscopic object at rest?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Let's consider a car left at the parking lot. The car is at rest, we know the exact position. But what about its velocity?

Does the Uncertainty Principle apply to the car (even if our nowadays instruments are not sophisticated enough to detect it)?

Comment: it does apply to the car, so you really do not know if it moves a little or its place is not fixed, but please  just use de prinziple to see if you can detect the difference!

Comment: If we can't detect, how do you know it DOES apply to the car? Conjecture? Obviously, we can't confirm it experimentally? It may be that our current instruments are not sophisticated, of course that is logical possibility. But it may be it just does NOT apply. That is another logical possibility. We can't answer it scientifically (empirically). In both cases it will be conjecture...

Comment: If you know one can not answer it empirically ,why do you ask?

Comment: I am interested to see how non-empirical answers are constructed and argumented...

Answer (score 4):

This is too long for a comment but there are lots of issues with your question.  What do you mean by "car at rest"?

1. The car is a composite object and the atoms in the material are certainly not at rest, and neither are the electrons in these material.  So what exactly are you measuring when you say the car is at rest?
2. Even if you consider the car as a strictly rigid body and eliminate the vibrations as per above, how do you know the car is at rest?  A bit of wind, car going nearby, even pedestrian walking nearly will make the car oscillate or vibrate just a bit, so the car will not strictly be at rest.
3. What do you use to measure the position of the car?  If you use any type of meter stick, that will not afford sufficient precision to detect small values $\Delta x$.
4. What do you use to measure the momentum of the car?

My point is: given the numerically small value of $\hbar$ (measured in SI units) $\Delta x\Delta p$ (also measured in SI units) is much greater than $\hbar/2$ for macroscopic objects because of all of the above, so yes the principle applies but it doesn't reveal anything.

Now it *is* possible to measure extremely precisely the change in the position of a macroscopic object, as exemplified by the LIGO detectors.  This is done under very controlled lab conditions so it's difficult to compare with a car, but the UR still holds.